# Pass data to previous viewcontroller VIPER

Tags: ios, swift, popviewcontroller, viper-architecture

I am using VIPER architecture in iOS swift. I have 2 viewcontrollers, let's say `A` and `B`. At first I'm going from `A` to `B`, performing some tasks and coming back from `B` to `A`. With MVC or MVVM, we can create protocols and transfer data from `B` to `A`. But for VIPER, i am confused. Here's my VIPER code B, while Back button is tapped:

View:

```
@IBAction func backButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    presenter?.goBack()
}
```

Presenter:

```
func goBack() {
    router.back()
}
```

Router:

```
func back() {
    viewController?.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    //here I want to send data back to previous viewcontroller
}
```

I have tried creating one method in the **Router** of **previous controller** and sending the data through that method but it is not working as router doesn't have any instance of presenter or anything else, except view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note:-  In Viper Router is Unidirectional.
So this might help you.

1. Implement ProtocolDelegate in Current Module's VC
2. Create a delegate variable in the Next Module's Router
3. Then Simply Send Delegate Dependancy to Next Module's Router
4. And Call your delegate method from Next Module's Router.

***Module A***

```
final class VCA: SomeProtocolDelegate {
 fund someMethod() {
      //Your task Action From Module B
    }
 }

final class ModuleARouter: WireFrameProtocol {
    fund gotoModuleB(withView vc: VCA) {
       ModuleBRouter.load(onView: vc)
    }
}
```

***Module B***

```
final class ModuleBRouter: WireframeProtocol {
    internal weak var delegate: SomeProtocolDelegate?
    // Here you  can add more argument on load method for delegate 
    // since in this example i'm send data back ViewController So I didn't create 
    class func load(onView VC: UIViewController) {
        //setup your VIPER protocol and class
        if let vCA = VC as? VCA {
            router.delegate = vCA
        }
    }

   func backToPreviousModule() {
      self.delegate?. someMethod()
   }
}
```